# button as submit form

Tags: php, html

im trying to make something, and now i came to the part where i created a button that should lock the topic, but i don't know how to make it work like submit form, when i press it it should lock the topic, but nothing happens:

```
    echo '<br><div class="ticket_info">';
    if($stanje == 0 ) {  
       echo ' <button class="lockticket" name="lockticketbutton">Zatvori</button></a> ';
    }
    else if($stanje != 0 ) {
         echo ' <button class="lockticket" name="unlockticketbutton">Otvori</button></a>';  
    }

    echo '
       Postavio: '.$output['Postavio'].' --- ['.$output['Naslov'].']

    </div>

    </br><div class="ticket_info2">

    '.$output['Text'].'

    </div>

    ';
```

And this is what it should output:

```
if(isset($_POST['lockticketbutton']))
{
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $query = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `Dashboard` SET `Status` = '1' WHERE `ID` = '$id'");

    if($query)
    {
      header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    }
    else
    {
        header('location: dashboard.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: post the whole code.

Comment: Please paste whole code, *dear*. Don't know from where `if(isset($_POST['odgovoritiket']))` it's coming .

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ZHZtNJyV

Comment: @Nathaniel Not on pastebin, post it here... ;-)

Comment: Ok, i've edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can submit the button by using following code

```
<form action ="your php file name" method ="post">
    <button type= "submit" class="lockticket" name="odgovoritiket" >Otvori</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

To use a button as Submit you need to put it into `form`.

**Note**: according to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp):

> If you use the `<button>` element in an HTML form, different browsers may submit different values. Use `<input>` to create buttons in an HTML form.

Comment: That must be an old page on W3Schools, back from when their information was wildly inaccurate.